# python how to force users to log into a socket server to use python script

Tags: python, sockets, security, server, ip

I am creating security for my python script requiring the user to input a username and password which will be sent to a server which will then check if the username and password exists. If it does, I want it to allow the person to use the software. I have done all this however I cant find a solution to multiple people using the same username and password. How can I prevent multiple people accessing the software using the same login.

Below is server code at the moment:

```
import socket
import threading
import sys

class Server():

    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    connections = []
    def __init__(self):
        self.sock.bind(("0.0.0.0", 10000))
        self.sock.listen(1)
        mystring = "Welcome"
        mystrinf = "Not allowed"
        self.b = mystring.encode('utf-8')
        self.d = mystrinf.encode("utf-8")
    def handler(self, c, a):
        while True:
            data = c.recv(2024)
            dara = data.decode("utf-8")
            for connection in self.connections:
                with open(r"C:\Users\Tom\PycharmProjects\untitled\names.txt") as f:
                    if dara in [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]:
                        connection.send(self.b)
                        print(data)
                        break
                    else:
                        connection.send(self.d)
                        print(data)
                        break
            if not data:
                self.connections.remove(c)
                c.close()
                break

    def run(self):
        while True:
            c, a = self.sock.accept()
            cThread = threading.Thread(target=self.handler, args=(c,a))
            cThread.daemon = True
            cThread.start()
            self.connections.append(c)
            print(self.connections)



server = Server()
server.run()
```

and here is a sample of a client:

```
import socket

host = "********"
port = 10000                
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host, port))
lol = input("?")
l = lol.encode("utf-8")
s.sendall(l)
data = s.recv(1024)
dara = data.decode("utf-8")
s.close()
print('Received', repr(dara))
```

Comment: It may not be as big of a problem as you think. What if someone wanted to use the software on two different computers? Anyway, you’d have to keep a list of logged in users to access every time someone wanted to log in.

Comment: @Steampunkery Thinking about it that makes sense. I was thinking of a geo logger or other more complex ways but a logged in list may help. Will post if I solve my own question!

Comment: On same network ?

Comment: You could periodically check if the software is still allowed to run. being allowed to run means that there is only one instance of a login/pw in use during this time slot. Logging off would clear the counter. Logging on would invalidate the previous connection.

Comment: @dsgdfg no I want people to access server from anywhere but one account per user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for me at the moment was to use @Steampunkery's idea and just keep a dictionary with all usernames having a value of online or offline like this:

```
Users = {}
with open(r"---LOCATION OF USERNAMES---") as users:
    for user in users:
        cuser = user.replace('\n', "")
        Users[cuser.lower()] = "offline"
```

I would then just change the value to online when they are connected and change it back when they disconnect.

Thanks for the help.